# Linear operator defined by its eigenvectors/values

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $(e_n)$ a complete orthonormal sequence, and $\lambda_n$ a bounded sequence of complex numbers. Let $A$ be defined such that the $(e_n)$ are the eigenvectors of $A$ and the $(\lambda_n)$ are its eigenvalues. That is, let

$$A(\sum x_n e_n) = \sum \lambda_n x_n e_n$$

whenever the sum converges. Then I know how to prove that, if $(\lambda_n) \rightarrow 0$ then $A$ is compact---I just need to pick an appropriate sequence of pairwise orthogonal projections and apply a theorem.

My question is the converse, proving that **if $A$ is compact, then $(\lambda_n)$ must converge to 0**. By assuming $A$ is compact I get the following:

1. A is bounded and therefore continuous
2. For any bounded sequence $(z_n)$ in $H$, $(Az_n)$ has a convergent subsequence

but I don't know if these two observations are enough or if I need some other piece to get the ball rolling. Furthermore, do I need to tack on any additional conditions to get self-adjointness, or can I prove that as-is?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to show that $A$ is compact.

Comment: If the $e_n$ are orthonormal, and $\lambda_{n_k}$ is a sequence with $|\lambda_{n_k}| \ge \delta >0$, then $Ae_{n_k}$ is a sequence such that the distance between any two elements is $\ge \sqrt{2} \delta$, hence cannot have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Oh, that's slick. If you post that as an answer I'll happily upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $e_n$ are orthonormal, and $\lambda_{n_k}$ is a sequence with $|\lambda_{n_k}| \ge \delta >0 $, then $A e_{n_k}$ is a sequence such that the distance between any two elements is $\ge \sqrt{2} \delta$, hence cannot have a convergent subsequence.